# Why is Swift inferring double values when using literals?

Tags: swift, type-inference

I understand that Swift is very strict about types and does not implicitly cast one type to another.

Why does this not generate an error and the output is an array of doubles?

```
let myDoubles = [Double.Pi, 42]
```

But this does?

```
let fortyTwoInt = 42;
let myDoubles = [Double.Pi, one]
```

Why does it implicitly cast 42 to 42.0 in the first example? And if it is not casting, what else is happening?

Simpler example:

```
let someFloat = 2.0 + 2
```

versus

```
let twoInt = 2
let someFloat = 2.0 + twoInt
```

Again, the latter one does not work.

Comment: The Reference Manual (section [Lexical Structure](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/LexicalStructure.html#ID414)) says: *"A literal doesn’t have a type on its own. Instead, a literal is parsed as having infinite precision and Swift’s type inference attempts to infer a type for the literal."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Cast" is not really the right word here. It interprets the character sequence "4" and "2" as an integer literal. `Double` conforms to `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral`, so the `Double` can be constructed from it.

`fortyTwoInt` is not an integer literal. It's an `Int`. And Swift will not automatically convert between `Int` and `Double`.